# Excel number and string comparison

Tags: excel, comparison

I want to write a function in excel to test if user entered a valid note name for given string number in a guitar.

```
6th string(E) - mi
5th string(A) - la
4th string(D) - re
3rd string(G) - sol
2nd string(B) - si
1st string(E) - mi

  A  B   C
1 2  si  true
2 4  re  true
3 5  sol false
4 6  mi  true
. .  .   .
```

Column A will be random generated between [1-6] as string number. User will input column B as corresponding musical note. I want to write the function for column C which will test if random generated string number matches user entered note name. What would be the most efficient function to do this comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Choose() function for that. Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

The formula in cell C1 is

```
=B1=CHOOSE(A1,"mi","si","sol","re","la","mi")
```

If your scenario is more complex than this example, you may want to consider a table where each note name text is matched to a value and use a lookup table instead.

[image]

This example is not related to the guitar strings, though, just the position of the note name on the scale. Adjust as suits.